# RingCentral Platform OAuth Tokens

Tags: api, token, platform, ringcentral

What is the Maximum Number of tokens that can be issued to a User in a RingCentral Platform?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit in the number of tokens that can be issued, however, there is a throttling limit on the number of OAuth Calls per minute per RingCentral extension(user). 5 OAuth Calls/min/extension. We strongly suggest to reuse the active access token and handle token expiration gracefully

Answer (score 0):

there is no limit in the number of tokens, but there is a rate limit of each APIs, you can get the rate limit in the header of the response.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, THere is no limit on issuing on OAuth tokens to any API of ring central.